# SQL Server foreign key with several cascading paths

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I have three tables in SQL Server 2014.

- First one is a `Product` table (productid, ...)
- Second one contains `ProductVersions` of that product (ProductVersionID, ProductID, ...)
- Third one contains licenses for the products (LicenseID, ProductID)

These tables have foreign keys on the product ID with on delete cascade.

Now I want to add another table mapping the licenses to specific `ProductVersions`. This can be a n:m relationship, so I create an mapping table `LicenseVersion` (`LicenseID, ProductVersionID`)

When I try to add an foreign key to that relations I get an error saying can't add foreign key because there are loops or serveral cascading paths. Use on delete no action or change the foreign key.

I think, I get why this happens (deleting the product will cause the `LicenseVersion` row to be deleted from both ways in one transaction) but what is the best practice to solve this?

The database should be consistent anytime, so I don't want to solve this in the software application logic.

I could use a trigger (I think) and an foreign key with no action, but is this the best way?

[image: database diagram]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products]
(
   [ProductID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [ProductName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Products] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([ProductID] ASC)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductVersions]
(
   [ProductVersionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
   [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ProductVersions] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ProductVersionID] ASC)
) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[License]
(
   [LicenseId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [LicenseName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
   [ProductId] [int] NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.License] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([LicenseId] ASC)
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ProductId] 
     ON [dbo].[License] ([ProductId] ASC)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ProductID] 
     ON [dbo].[ProductVersions] ([ProductID] ASC)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[License] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.License_dbo.Products_ProductId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([ProductId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Products] ([ProductID])
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
                ON DELETE CASCADE

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[License] CHECK CONSTRAINT     [FK_dbo.License_dbo.Products_ProductId]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProductVersions]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ProductVersions_dbo.Products_ProductID] 
        FOREIGN KEY([ProductID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Products] ([ProductID])
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
                ON DELETE CASCADE

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProductVersions] CHECK CONSTRAINT     [FK_dbo.ProductVersions_dbo.Products_ProductID]


--add new table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LicenseVersion]
(
   [LicenseID] [int] NOT NULL,
   [ProductVersionID] [int] NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT [PK_LicenseVersion] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([LicenseID] ASC, [ProductVersionID] ASC)
) 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LicenseVersion] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_LicenseVersion_ProductVersions] 
        FOREIGN KEY([ProductVersionID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ProductVersions] ([ProductVersionID])
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
                ON DELETE CASCADE

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LicenseVersion] CHECK CONSTRAINT     [FK_LicenseVersion_ProductVersions]

--error here:
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LicenseVersion]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_LicenseVersion_Licenses] 
        FOREIGN KEY([LicenseID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[License] ([LicenseID])
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
                ON DELETE CASCADE

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LicenseVersion] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_LicenseVersion_Licenses]
```

Comment: Images are not good for this type of thing. Why? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 What would be better is the ddl for those tables.

Comment: I'm sorry, I added the code

Comment: You have circular logic here. If you have cascade deletes running through everything you could literally empty every table with a single delete. Try to follow the cascading logic across those four tables. It can just keep going and going and going and going because all the rows reference each other.

Comment: I don't see that circle. Deleting a ProductVersion would cause the LicenseVersion Table to be deleted and stop. Deleting a License would cause the LicenseVersion table to be deleted and stop. Deleting a Product would cause the ProductVersion table to be deleted and the LicenseVersion table to be deleted and the license table with the already deleted LicenseVersion. And then stop. No loop, "just" 2 cascading paths. And question was, what's the best way to handle this.

Comment: The circular logic is there. You are thinking about the structure the way you intend to use it. The structure would allow the circular logic to take off that is why you get that error. Remove the update and delete cascades on the LicenseVersion check. Then your system is unable to get invalid data. You will need to add the logic to handle the update and delete yourself.